# Not able to view records in Child Account related list

Tags: page-layout

I have a child related list on Account. The child records have different record type than parent. I am able to view the related list name and layout but records are not appearing in the related list.

[image]

Background: I want to pre-populate some fields of Parent Account in child so I have created a Aura component which opens when a custom button on related list is clicked. This is working fine in sandbox but on production records are not showing.

Even if I remove the custom button and add standard new button the records are not appearing.

Security: Accounts OWD is public read/write. User has access to all the fields. User can view parent and child account in separate windows. when clicking on parent name from child account I am able to navigating to parent account. Record type access is also there.